# Javascript to populate a form field with data extracted from URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I am trying to use javascript to extract data from the URL parameter 'utm_source' and add it to a field on a form so that it is stored in my contact database for tracking purposes.

I had previously accomplished this on another site, but when trying to reuse the code it is not working for me.

The page is here (with the included URL parameter to be extracted):

https://members.travisraab.com/country-guitar-clinic-optin-1-1?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=description

The desired result if for the 'traffic_source' field on my form to be populated with the value from the 'utm_source' URL parameter, in this case 'youtube'.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addSource() {
  var fieldToChange = document.getElementsByName("form_submission[custom_4]");
  var source = trafficSource();
  fieldToChange.value = source;
  }

  var trafficSource = function() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == "utm_source"){
          return pair[1];
      } else if (pair[0] == "gclid") {
          return 'google';
      }
    }
    return 'unknown';
  }


document.onload = addSource();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fieldToChange` is a NodeList so if you want to change the value property you need to specify the index number

So this should fix your code

```
fieldToChange[0].value = source;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the query params using `new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` and get the particular query param using `searchParams.get('utm_source')` and then, store the value of `utm_source` in form field using `document.getElementById("utmsource").value = param;`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="utmsource" />
    <script>
        let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        let param = searchParams.get('utm_source')
        document.getElementById("utmsource").value = param;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```